Mongodb Map-Reduce perform multiple aggregations
Let's say that I have a collection with documents of this form:
{
    id: id1,
    name: foo,
    value: 64
},
{
    id: id1,
    name: bar,
    value: 37
},
{
    id: id1,
    name: bar,
    value: 30
},
...

I want, for each id, to get the 'name' field with the maximum sum of values. I need to do it using MapReduce, not MongoDB queries. For instance, in the example above, the output would be:
{
    id: id1,
    name: bar
}

Conceptually, it's very simple. The problem is that, when it comes to applying it in MapReduce, I need to first group by the name field and make that sum, and THEN group by "id" and find the maximum. And the problem is that, if I emit as a key the id field, then I will sum all the values regardless of their name; and if I emit as a key both the id and name fields, then I will have the sum correctly performed, but in the "finalize" function I will not have the rest of the name values to find out the maximum, so I will be left with only the sum.
So far I have implemented something similar to emitting also an empty object which keeps track of the sum for each name, but I am having trouble making it idempotent, associative and commutative... This is what I have so far:


// map
function() { 
  var key =  this.id
  var value = {
    biomass_value: this.value,
    scientific_name: this.name,
  }
  if (this.value !== "ERROR") {
    emit(key, value);
  }
}

// reduce
function(key, value) {
    var groupBy = function(data, key, sum_field) { // `data` is an array of objects, `key` is the key (or property accessor) to group by
        // reduce runs this anonymous function on each element of `data` (the `item` parameter,
        // returning the `storage` parameter at the end
        return data.reduce(function(storage, item) {
            // get the first instance of the key by which we're grouping
            var group = item[key];
            
            // set `storage` for this instance of group to the outer scope (if not empty) or initialize it
            storage[group] = storage[group] || 0;
            storage[group] = storage[group] + item[sum_field];which will then loop through the next 
            return storage; 
        }, {}); // {} is the initial value of the storage
    };
    var out = groupBy(value, "scientific_name", "biomass_value")
    var max_value = 0;
    var max_name = "";
    Object.keys(out).forEach(key => {
        var value = out[key];
        if (value > max_value) {
            max_value = value;
            max_name = key;
        }
    })
    return {name: max_name, value: max_value};
}



I know that this could be done easily with a MongoDB query. In fact, I do have it. But it's an assignment, and we are required to do everything in MapReduce, and in a single iteration of it; so please, do not tell me that I should be using $aggregate, I know, but I am not allowed to.
Thanks in advance!

"should be using $aggregate, I know, but I can't" Can't because you are not allowed to or because you don't know how to?

Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a minimal reproducible example, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. For further information, see How to Ask, and take the tour.

@aneroid Not allowed to. I already have it solved with "aggregate", I know what I should be getting. But I need it done with MapReduce to qualify.
